# Age Verify Plugin for WP

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am using Age Verify plugin for wordpress which gives you two options one is text, where user types in their Date of Month, Date and Year and other is a drop down list for Month, Date and Year. Text has a place holder for input fields as MM DD and YY, but drop down does not and its starts at January, 01 and Current year. I would like to implement the place holders for drop down as well, but not sure how. Please help.

Here's the php responsible for displaying the drop down date of birth:

```
$form.='<p><select name="av_verify_m" id="av_verify_m">';

foreach ( range( 1, 12 ) as $month ) :

    $month_name = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1 ) );

    $form .= '<option value="' . $month . '">' . $month_name . '</option>';

endforeach;

$form .= '</select> - <select name="av_verify_d" id="av_verify_d">';

foreach ( range( 1, 31 ) as $day ) :

    $form .= '<option value="' . $day . '">' . esc_html( zeroise( $day, 2 ) ) .    '</option>';

endforeach;

$form .= '</select> - <select name="av_verify_y" id="av_verify_y">';

foreach ( range( 1910, date( 'Y' ) ) as $year ) :

    $selected = ( $year == date( 'Y' ) ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

    $form .= '<option value="' . $year . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $year . '</option>';

endforeach;

$form .= '</select></p>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't a place to ask people to just code for you, which is basically what you're asking.

But since it's so simple, I'll throw you a bone.

```
$form.='<p><select name="av_verify_m" id="av_verify_m">';

$form.='<option value="" disabled selected>MM</option>';

foreach ( range( 1, 12 ) as $month ) :

    $month_name = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1 ) );

    $form .= '<option value="' . $month . '">' . $month_name . '</option>';

endforeach;

$form .= '</select> - <select name="av_verify_d" id="av_verify_d">';

$form.='<option value="" disabled selected>DD</option>';

foreach ( range( 1, 31 ) as $day ) :

    $form .= '<option value="' . $day . '">' . esc_html( zeroise( $day, 2 ) ) .    '</option>';

endforeach;

$form .= '</select> - <select name="av_verify_y" id="av_verify_y">';

$form.='<option value="" disabled selected>YY</option>';

foreach ( range( 1910, date( 'Y' ) ) as $year ) :

    $selected = ( $year == date( 'Y' ) ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

    $form .= '<option value="' . $year . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $year . '</option>';

endforeach;

$form .= '</select></p>';
```

Comment: Sure thing... please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it works for you.